# Input mysql query from JTextarea from user and showing output in JTable as it happens in SQLYog

Tags: java, mysql

I am developing an swing based application that
will provide GUI to mysql command line.
I want to input queries from user and display output to JTable
by directly connecting to mysql.exe so that u can simply execute that query on
mysql command line and get output in JTable or error in message for wrong syntax  etc.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Sir, I want to  write query in JTextArea and  execute it on mysql command line . How to do this?